# SharePoint Online JSON formatting - Conditional Popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I've created a custom view that includes a popup description of each file in my SharePoint library.

This works well when I'm within a sub-folder that has a list of files, but when I navigate to the main list of sub-folders within the library the custom formatting continues and a blank pop up appears because the folders don't have descriptions.

Is there a way to use conditional formatting so that the pop-up only appears for rows that have text in the description column?

This is my code currently:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "16px",
    "color": "white"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$Description]",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding": "10px",
        "width": "500px",
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "white"
      }
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show/hide `customCardProps` conditionally. You have to show/hide the element where you added `customCardProps`. So, you need to create two elements and show/hide them based on value of **Description** field.

Try below JSON code, it should work for you:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "16px",
    "color": "white"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Description] == '', 'block', 'none')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Description] == '', 'none', 'block')"
      },
      "customCardProps": {
        "formatter": {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "[$Description]",
          "style": {
            "font-size": "14px",
            "padding": "10px",
            "width": "500px",
            "color": "black",
            "background-color": "white"
          }
        },
        "openOnEvent": "hover",
        "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
        "isBeakVisible": true,
        "beakStyle": {
          "backgroundColor": "white"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

**Update from comments**:

You can refer to the column formatting JSON schema at: https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json

You can see that there is no `style` property supported for `customCardProps`:

[image]

Comment: You can add style to customCardProps, the OP already uses it! and I also have tried it on my side and it's working as expected! so Have you tried my solution before saying you can't?!!

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution and it is still showing blank popup (Did you really tried it on your site?). And I didn't say we cannot apply style to `customCardProps`. I am saying that we cannot make it show/hide conditionally (You have to hide the element where you added `customCardProps` like I did in my solution). And the `style` you are referring is applied to `div` element inside `customCardProps` not applied directly to `customCardProps`. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Whoever blindly downvoted my solution should try it on their site OR can refer to the my updated answer OR can refer to the Microsoft official JSON schema and see that `style` property is not supported for `customCardProps` at:  https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json

Comment: Thanks Ganesh this works whether you include the popup tip or not!

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the `description` is not empty using the below condition in `customCardProps`

```
"display": "=if(([$Description] ==''),'none','block')"
```

**Full JSON**

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "16px",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$Description]",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding": "10px",
        "width": "500px",
        "color": "black",
        "background-color": "white",
        "display": "=if(([$Description] ==''),'none','block')"
      }
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118142/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-sharepoint-online-json-formatting).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: @Toby Are you able to see a small blank pop up when you hover over the folder where description field is blank?

Comment: @GaneshSanap So I just realised this solution only works if you don't include the popup tip (which I had since decided I didn't want) - "isBeakVisible": false. If you include the tip then it still appears.

Comment: +1 for animated image