# Is there any way using column formatting if i can show it as a hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, column-formatting, fieldcustomizers

[image][image]

Hi I have a cascading lookup column in sharepoint modern view. That column is redering as html.I am new to column formatting and when i use this code it converts the whole html into link. What i want is it should only take the lookup value and show it as a link. Please refer to the image below.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='www.google.com' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lookup fields are also represented as objects; the display text is stored in the lookupValue property. As I am not sure about your list setup so only suggestions based on assumption. First try with `@currentField.lookupValue` instead of `@currentField`, if the look up field has value of part of the URL and you are trying to rebuild a full URL. More information about your list will be helpful.

Update:
Try with the json below:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue"
}
```

Comment: Hi  thanks for quick reply i have tried using @currentField.lookupValue but then the whole column appears as blank . The two fields shown in the image are cascading looup columns and its a customized form so the code is working fine in classic sharepoint pages but its is rendering as markup in modern sites. I have attached list schema .

Comment: @nehagharpure. OK I see you problem. JSON formatting simply works for modern experience. And if you are using script to modify the column value in the form in classic experience, I am not sure it will work as you want (in modern experience) to change the formatting of the customized field.

Comment: @nehagharpure. So if the cascading lookup works fine for you, I will suggest keeping on the code way to customize. Modern experience does not support script editor to customize. If you still try to work with JSON formatting, you may need another way to create the cascade dropdown, like using PowerApps.

Comment: I am trying to edit in modern view only. But the thing is that i dont know how to fetch the lookup column value displayed in between the anchor tags. Is there any way i can get those value. Since i am new to column formatting i dont know how to work with loop index or for each loop .

Comment: One thing I would like to confirm. In you new screenshot, I find that two columns are "Cascading Dropdown" Field. As in SharePoint Online, we do not have such  column type, I would like to know if you are using some 3rd party tools. JSON formatting supports lookup column. The lookup column object simply has ID and value, by default @currentField.lookupValue or [$FieldName.lookupValue] shall both works. Please have a try with the test JSON I updated in the reply. If it still goes blank, it may be a bit more complex.

Comment: It appears  blank. I have attached screen shot.

Comment: Yes, I see. I will assume some 3rd party tool is used to create the cascade dropping down column, correct ? I mean by default we do not have such column type. If you can create a cascading dropdown via UI. There is a high probability some custom solutions are used. And JSON formatting will simply not support.

Comment: Hi @Jerry_MSFT  Its SP2019 and when i create a new lookup column i can see the option for cascading lookup.I think some script is used to show link but now it is displayed as markup. Also i have one more query is there any way to show pop ups on click of hyperlink using column formating and if no is there any microsoft document stating the same.

Comment: For click popup, we will need to use customCardProps element to hold the content you want to display. And set the openOnEvent to click. Here is an example with useful documentations you can refer to:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288576/sharepoint-online-json-formatting-conditional-popup