# Help with JSON code for SharePoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a document library that I want users to  be able to add a photo to with a title and descriptions and others be able to hover over the pic in gallery view and see the description AND be able to "like" the pic as well.

I have most of this figured out but can't get the text to show in my hover:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
      "height": 210,
      "width": 254,
      "hideSelection": true,
      "fillHorizontally": true,
      "formatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-container"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "button",
            "style": {
              "z-index": "9"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
              "role": "presentation"
            },
            "customRowAction": {
              "action": "defaultClick"
            },
            "customCardProps": {
              "formatter": {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "[$Description]",
                "style": {
                    "font-size": "12px",
                    "color": "black",
                    "padding": "5px"
          }
              },
              "openOnEvent": "hover",
              "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
              "isBeakVisible": true,
              "beakStyle": {
                "backgroundColor": "white"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "position": "relative"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer ms-fontColor-white"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "position": "absolute",
                  "bottom": "0",
                  "right": "0",
                  "z-index": "10",
                  "overflow": "hidden",
                  "cursor": "pointer",
                  "display": "flex",
                  "align-items": "center",
                  "width": "100%",
                  "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-black--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "display": "flex",
                      "width": "100%"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "txtContent": "[$Title]",
                        "style": {
                          "width": "100%",
                          "padding": "10px"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "attributes": {
                          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-white ms-fontColor-black--hover"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "border-radius": "6px",
                          "display": "flex"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                              "display": "=if(indexOf([$LikedBy.email], @me) == -1, 'flex', 'none')",
                              "padding": "10px",
                              "align-items": "center"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                              "iconName": "Heart"
                            },
                            "customRowAction": {
                              "action": "setValue",
                              "actionInput": {
                                "LikesTotal": "=Number(length(appendTo([$LikedBy], @me)))",
                                "LikedBy": "=appendTo([$LikedBy], @me)"
                              }
                            },
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "txtContent": "[$LikesTotal]",
                                "style": {
                                  "font-size": "12px",
                                  "margin-left": "4px",
                                  "font-family": "Segoe UI"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                              "display": "=if(indexOf([$LikedBy.email], @me) == -1, 'none', 'flex')",
                              "padding": "10px",
                              "align-items": "center"
                            },
                            "attributes": {
                              "iconName": "HeartFill"
                            },
                            "customRowAction": {
                              "action": "setValue",
                              "actionInput": {
                                "LikesTotal": "=Number(length(removeFrom([$LikedBy], @me)))",
                                "LikedBy": "=removeFrom([$LikedBy], @me)"
                              }
                            },
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "elmType": "div",
                                "txtContent": "[$LikesTotal]",
                                "style": {
                                  "font-size": "12px",
                                  "margin-left": "4px",
                                  "font-family": "Segoe UI"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "filepreview",
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "@thumbnail.512x432"
                        },
                        "style": {
                          "height": "200px"
                        },
                        "filePreviewProps": {
                          "brandTypeIconStyle": {
                            "display": "none"
                          },
                          "fileTypeIconStyle": {
                            "display": "none"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you make sure that you filled `Description` field value because your JSON looks correct anyway. By default `Description` field is read only so you can follow [this](https://sharepointstuff.com/2022/01/12/description-column-sharepoint-libraries/) to enable it. Please try it and let know whether it works for you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint default Description column added to document library, you will have to use correct internal name of this column which is `_ExtendedDescription`.

You can get the internal name of any column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

But this column is not a plain text column. So, you will see the HTML tags in your custom hover card.

So, I will suggest you to create a new multiple lines of text (plain text) column in your document library and use it for adding description to your images.

**Library view (with metadata)**:

[image]

**Tiles view (after applying JSON)**:

[image]

**JSON**: Similar to what you added to your question - just used the column names as per my setup

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 210,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "style": {
          "z-index": "9"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        },
        "customCardProps": {
          "formatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "txtContent": "[$CustomDescription]",
            "style": {
              "font-size": "12px",
              "color": "black",
              "padding": "5px"
            }
          },
          "openOnEvent": "hover",
          "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
          "isBeakVisible": true,
          "beakStyle": {
            "backgroundColor": "white"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "position": "relative"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer ms-fontColor-white"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "position": "absolute",
              "bottom": "0",
              "right": "0",
              "z-index": "10",
              "overflow": "hidden",
              "cursor": "pointer",
              "display": "flex",
              "align-items": "center",
              "width": "100%",
              "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-bgColor-black--hover"
                },
                "style": {
                  "display": "flex",
                  "width": "100%"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "[$Title]",
                    "style": {
                      "width": "100%",
                      "padding": "10px"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-white ms-fontColor-black--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "border-radius": "6px",
                      "display": "flex"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "span",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(indexOf([$LikedBy.email], @me) == -1, 'flex', 'none')",
                          "padding": "10px",
                          "align-items": "center"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "iconName": "Heart"
                        },
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "LikesTotal": "=Number(length(appendTo([$LikedBy], @me)))",
                            "LikedBy": "=appendTo([$LikedBy], @me)"
                          }
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "txtContent": "[$LikesTotal]",
                            "style": {
                              "font-size": "12px",
                              "margin-left": "4px",
                              "font-family": "Segoe UI"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elmType": "span",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if(indexOf([$LikedBy.email], @me) == -1, 'none', 'flex')",
                          "padding": "10px",
                          "align-items": "center"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "iconName": "HeartFill"
                        },
                        "customRowAction": {
                          "action": "setValue",
                          "actionInput": {
                            "LikesTotal": "=Number(length(removeFrom([$LikedBy], @me)))",
                            "LikedBy": "=removeFrom([$LikedBy], @me)"
                          }
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "txtContent": "[$LikesTotal]",
                            "style": {
                              "font-size": "12px",
                              "margin-left": "4px",
                              "font-family": "Segoe UI"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "filepreview",
                    "attributes": {
                      "src": "@thumbnail.512x432"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "height": "200px"
                    },
                    "filePreviewProps": {
                      "brandTypeIconStyle": {
                        "display": "none"
                      },
                      "fileTypeIconStyle": {
                        "display": "none"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you want to show/hide custom hover card conditionally based on if description column is blank or not, follow my answer at: [SharePoint Online JSON formatting - Conditional Popup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288576/sharepoint-online-json-formatting-conditional-popup/288583#288583)

Comment: Truly Ganesh, you are such a huge wealth of knowledge.  Thank you, again!!  This worked perfectly!!!! :) :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!